# Why is node js returning all tinyint data even though I select * where it is 0?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, phpmyadmin

I tried the same sql command in phpmyadmin and it works fine but different in node js so I don't think it's a problem with the sql command.

```
  app.get('/tag/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    
  
    console.log(id);
      connection.query("SELECT * from news   WHERE ? = 0",id, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
      else {
            res.send(results) 
      };
  });
   
 })
```

When I use the

```
SELECT * from news WHERE ? = 0
```

It will return all values.

But when I use

```
   SELECT * from news WHERE ? = 1
```

It doesn't return any values ​​at all.

This is my database structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUXS0.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh966.jpg)

Comment: It's better to give any information in text (not screenshots), so people can copy-paste the code if they want to try it themselves. Also, better to use western alphabet. Even if the language is not familiar, people can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to select to use which boolean field to select on? This can't be done using query parameters.